# Booking a "12 hour use" hotel room at the Incheon Airport Transit Hotel

Tags: bookings, hotels, icn

I want to book a room at the Incheon Airport Transit Hotel in South Korea.  They have a rate for a "12 hour use" room.  I'm booking it on hotels.com but there's nothing that lets me specify exactly which 12 hours I want.  I just have a check-in date and check-out date (which I specified to be April 15th and April 16th, respectively).

Here's an example of what I see [on Hotels.com](https://www.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?q-check-out=2017-04-16&q-check-in=2017-04-15&WOE=7&WOD=6&q-room-0-children=0&tab=description&q-room-1-children=0&hotel-id=435576&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-1-adults=2&q-room-2-adults=2&YGF=14&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3&q-room-2-children=0)

How does this work exactly? Does this assume I want to stay the night?  Do the 12 hours begin when I check in?

Answer (score 6):

As a transit hotel, it allows those with international connections to sleep and refresh before an onward journey. If you will click through to the [Arriving/Leaving link, it explains](https://www.hotels.com/ho435576/incheon-airport-transit-hotel-incheon-south-korea/):

> This hotel is located in the customs area of the airport, and only international travelers can access the property. Guests are asked to communicate in advance the number of their flight, and their check-in and check-out times at the time of booking. Contact information is provided in the reservation confirmation email. The hotel is located in the customs area, so guests should not pass immigration. Luggage will be transferred to the guest's next flight. To reach the hotel, guests must follow the transit arrows to boarding gate No.43/No.11 on the 3rd floor, then take the escalator near the gate to the 4th floor.

Comment: Hmm.. my plan was to stay here for the night after arriving from a flight from the U.S. and then travel to the Gimpo airport in the morning to catch a domestic flight there.  Does this mean I cannot stay at this hotel? (i.e., Am I considered a "traveler transiting between international flights"?)

Comment: You're transiting from international to domestic. A hotel like this, airside, gives int'l passengers the advantage of not having to go through customs and immigration before boarding their next int'l flight. I don't see why not, but better to ask the hotel directly @SpehroPefhany has given you a link.

Comment: @nukeguy - You can not use the transit hotel, as you need to clear immigration, then claim your bags and enter Korea to transfer to Gimpo for a domestic flight.  You will not be able to reach the transit hotel, as you will not be able to show a boarding pass or eticket to enter the transit zone, instead airport staff will send you direct to immigration.  Even if you do talk your way through to the transit lounge, you will have the headache of tracking your bags down in the am. Better bet is to find a hotel near Gimpo with airport transfer services and spend the night there.

Answer (score 2):

That seems awfully expensive for 12 hours at a 3-star hotel even considering the convenience factor. Must be for one day, I think. You can't expect the booking sites to have contingencies for every variation of the hotels.

You can contact [them directly](https://www.walkerhill.com/transithotel/en/room/Deluxe.jsp): The FAQ and rates pages explain exactly how it works. Note that there are 10% + 10% additional charges on top of the Korean won prices.

[image]

I use 'Skype out' so the phone call would cost almost nothing, but there's an e-mail on the contact information page as well.

Comment: If you scroll down, they have a 12 hour price and a higher 24 hour price.  I only need it for 12 hours since I cannot stay longer than that anyway.  I will likely try contacting them directly.  Thanks!

Comment: 138,000 KRW + 10% +10% is USD $118 plus a couple percent for conversion, which is more reasonable.